# Question about for loops inside while loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

In this particular program:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import random
# Make a list of words
words = ['apple','banana','orange','coconut','strawberry','lime','grapefruit','lemon','kumquat', 
'blueberry','melon']

while True:
    start = input("Press enter/return to start, or enter Q to quit: \n")
    if start.lower() == 'q':
            break
    # Pick a Random Number
    secret_word = random.choice(words)
    bad_guesses = []
    good_guesses = []
    while len(bad_guesses) < 7 and len(good_guesses) != len(list(secret_word)):
    # Draw guesses letters, spaces and strikes
        for letter in secret_word:
            if letter in good_guesses:
                print(letter, end = "")
            else:
                print('_', end = "")
                print('')
                print('Strikes: {}/7'.format(len(bad_guesses)))
                print('')
                # Take guess
                guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
                if len(guess) != 1:
                    print("You can only guess a single letter !")
                    continue
                elif guess in bad_guesses or guess in good_guesses:
                    print("You've already guessed that letter !")
                    continue
                elif not guess.isalpha():
                    print("You can only guess letters !")
                    continue
                if guess in secret_word:
                    good_guesses.append(guess)
                    if len(good_guesses) == len(list(secret_word)):
                        print("YOU WIN !! The word was{}".format(secret_word))
                        break
                else:
                    bad_guesses.append(guess)

    else:
        print("You didn't guess it! My secret word was {}".format(secret_word))
```

I don't completely understand how the for loops inside the while loop works. I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general, so I apologize if the question I'm asking is too basic.
Does the program only check for the while loop condition after it finishes iterating over every letter in the for loop ? Or it checks for the while condition after each iteration of the for loop ( which seems more likely, yet less logical ).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only check the while loop once for each ENTIRE for loop, not each iteration.

For example, if you call count after the following,

```
count = 0
while count == 0:
    for i in range(10):
         count += 1
```

it will have a value of 10, but the while loop will exit because after the for loop has completed, count is no longer equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very basic question and it's answer is very simple as well. But worry not, we all start somewhere and it's a good thing you ask it; hope I help you understand this so it turns simple for you as well.

The outer loop always runs whatever is inside it, waits for the loop (whatever type of loop it is) to finish and then checks the condition (if any) to run through the loop again. This applies to loops inside loops as well (nested loops).
Coming to your example, it will first check if bad guesses is less than 7 and if the length of good__gesses is not equal to the length of secret_word. If this returns to be a valid condition then the 'for' loop inside will be run.

Hope this helps and enjoy programming!

Comment: Does this mean that in my example, say the secret word is ''apple'', the while loop can only check if the condition is true every five times I input a letter ? Because only then is the for loop finished, considering it iterates over letters of a 5 string word.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 yes, that's right. The while loop will count as "finished" for the first iteration after the for loop has been completed - which is going to be 5 times because "apple" has a length of 5. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question broadly, `for` and `while` loop conditions are checked before each iteration. For example,

```
while false:
    print("False")
```

will never reach the second line because the condition is not met before the first iteration.

But as long as the condition is met, all the code inside the loop will execute. The `loop` does not incrementally check its conditions - it only performs this check before attempting a new iteration. Consider this example:

```
foo = true
while foo == true:
    foo = false
    print(foo)
```

The `print` statement is reached because `foo` was true at the beginning of the loop. Naturally, this will only print once. Only when the loop attempts to repeat will the loop exit because the condition is not met - it will not exit prematurely unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to ask the question, no worries,

firstly you have to understand the loop concepts
in your case nested loop, you will understand it better if you study parent classes and child classes then it will surely ring a bell, it ringed for me :)

- while loop Repeats a statement or group of statements while a given condition is TRUE. It tests the condition before executing the loop body.

In while loop it tests the conditions first then only the loops starts.That is the main logic.

- for loop Executes a sequence of statements multiple times and abbreviates the code that manages the loop variable of body.
  but for loop starts and check for the times it have to run.